# compare output R with spss in Mancova

Tags: r, spss

I got it analyse mancova with R and spss. I want to compare their output. but result was very different 
 code mancova in R .Which results are correct R or spss? Is the code R written correctly? Please help me

```
library(jmv)
Data=read.csv(file.choose())
  Data
  attach(Data)
  names(Data)

> y2=mancova(data=Data,deps=vars(postGOcorrect,postNOgoerror,postRTgoerror
+         ,postRTNogoerror)
+         ,covs =vars(preGOcorrect,preNOgoerror,preRTgoerror
+                     ,preRTNOgoerror),
+         factors = group
+         , multivar = list("pillai", "wilks", "hotel", "roy"), boxM = TRUE,
+         shapiro = TRUE, qqPlot = TRUE)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

output spss

[image]
[image]

Comment: SPSS and R may use different type of sum of squares. I do not know about the jmv library to be sure what is doing exactly though.

Comment: Thank you. You recommend what non-jmv code I can use?
Thank you for guiding me@DimitriosZacharatos

Comment: Thank you. You recommend what non-jumbo code I can use
Thank you for guiding me  @DimitriosZacharatos

Comment: depends if you have a between subject design check the lm package

Comment: I don`t think . variables are independent  .I have 4 dependent and 4 covariate and two group. that I want to done  Multivariate analysis of covariance . I need to get it three table spss with R . I need table multivariate test and  table Tests of Between-Subjects Effects and table Univariate Tests with use from bonferroni test . Could you help me figure out what package to use for these tables in R   @DimitriosZacharatos

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124694/how-to-do-mancova-in-r

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the R jmv package doesn't explicitly say what kind of sums of squares are used or are default in its MANCOVA function, but it seems to be Type 1. SPSS uses Type 3 by default. The jmv package's ANOVA and ANCOVA functions use Type 3 by default as well. I tried using ss=3 to change this, as one can specify in ANOVA and ANCOVA, but that results in an error, and the documentation doesn't say how to specify the type of sums of squares for MANCOVA problems.

---

BTW, the output shown here the "Univariate Tests" table for SPSS for your example is showing results from the EMMEANS subcommand with COMPARE specified. The Bonferroni correction available with EMMEANS COMPARE is applied to multiple comparisons of groups, not to multiple dependent variables. Since there are only two groups here, the results will match the results from the Test of Between-Subjects effects for the group effect (assuming the EMMEANS COMPARE didn't fix the covariates as values other than their overall means).